# Is there any way to append a file to a zip with a different name in Java?

Tags: java, zip, rename, zipinputstream, zipoutputstream

I am wondering if there is a way, instead of just adding a file to a zip, to rename a file when adding it. I know of the write method:

```
(while ((len = zin.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
```

I have searched all over the internet and there is no information about it. Is there any class es, or methods Java has?
The only reason I don't want to rename then add it is because I'm working on windows with an aux file.
My whole code is:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile(zipFile.getName(), null);
    tempFile.delete();

    boolean renameOk=zipFile.renameTo(tempFile);
    if (!renameOk)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("could not rename the file "+zipFile.getAbsolutePath()+" to "+tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(tempFile));
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile));

    ZipEntry entry = zin.getNextEntry();
    while (entry != null) {
        String name = entry.getName();
        boolean notInFiles = true;
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.getName().equals(name)) {
                notInFiles = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (notInFiles) {
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
            int len;
            while ((len = zin.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 17, len);
            }
        }
        entry = zin.getNextEntry();
    }        
    zin.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName()));
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        out.closeEntry();
        in.close();
    }
    out.close();
    tempFile.delete();
```

Comment: Change the values of the `ZipEntry`...

Comment: What do you mean by change the values of the `ZipEntry`? Do you mean change the 0 in (buf, 0, len)?

Comment: This depends.  If you a are writing multiple files to a Zip file, each file should have a `ZipEntry`.  The `ZipEntry`, amongst other things, describes the directory and name of the file you are adding.  When you create a new `ZipEntry`, simply change the name it's name

Comment: I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Post a runnable example of what you are doing

Comment: Okay, I'm confused, what are you trying to rename?  The entries in the zip file or the actual file your adding?  I would, also, use the temp file as the location for the new zip.  This means if anything goes wrong, you've not lost the original file...

Comment: At the risk of repeating what MadProgrammer has said, I think maybe you are under the impression that entry names are part of the ZipOutputStream.  They are not.  The name you pass to the ZipEntry constructor *is* the new filename, period.  So to rename a file, pass a different string when constructing your ZipEntry.

Comment: Thanks guys, ajayajayaj